# JUnit - stop it from exiting on finish?

Tags: java, junit, exit

Quick JUnit question. I'm running some unit tests that involve starting up the GUI and doing a load of stuff.

I would like to see the results after the test to confirm it visually. However, it gets to the end of the code and exits, as it should. If I want to override this, I put a breakpoint on the last line of the test. This is pretty awkward though.

Is there some option to stop it from exiting?

Comment: involve starting up the GUI and doing a load of stuff - not a unit test

Comment: for UI related tests, I'd suggest Selenium - http://seleniumhq.org/

Comment: @Samuel: Perhaps my definitions are a bit off. But I need to start the GUI to perform the tests on different components.

Comment: yeah, that's great you're testing UI (it's much harder). I hope my selenium suggestion also helps =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the fact you require a GUI and user interaction during the execution of the test, this is a "functional" test rather than a "unit" test.

You could write the results to a file at the end, this would have the added benefit that you could assert that the output is correct/present programatically at the end. If you really want to keep the test running, then you could insert an infinite loop at the end of your test:

JUnit 3:

```
public void tearDown() {
    while (true) { Thread.sleep(2000); };
}
```

JUnit 4:

```
@After
public void tearDown() {
    while (true) { Thread.sleep(2000); };
}
```

This will keep the JUnit thread running, but you will need to ensure that your GUI events are being handled in another thread.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse: Run configurations... > Test > Keep JUnit running...

Comment: This was the answer to the title of your question. What is the nature of the GUI? For Swing there's http://www.jdemo.de/ which might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that your JUnit test is executing a tearDown() method, perhaps in a base class, which shuts down the GUI.  If so, you can override the tearDown() method in your JUnit test to prevent this behaviour.  E.g.

```
protected void tearDown()
{
   //do nothing
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but GUI still exits. I tried making the main class a field object just in case it was a garbage collector destroying the object. No luck there either

Answer (score 0):

How about using a [countdownlatch](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) which you count down.

private static CountDownLatch countdown = new CountDownLatch(1);

```
@AfterClass
public static void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
    countdown.await();
}
```

Then somewhere else in your code you count down latch on event.

```
countdown.countDown();
```

When `countdown.countDown()` is called then `countdown.await()` will continue.